# PHP Key value FOREACH

Tags: php

Ok I have a file that is trying to retrive job numbers out of a database call and then put them into key value pairs to return to my jquery function that will export them to my page. I am getting a 500 error when I try to run the page and it is on this page. What am I doing wrong with this output/call?

```
$output = new array();
$job = new job;
$jobs = $job->get_from_db( "`code` = '" . $_GET['term'] . "'" );

foreach ( $jobs as $key => $current)
    {
        $output[$key]['value'] = $current->code;
        $output[$key]['id'] = $current->id;
    }
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: SQL INJECTION. That is all.

Comment: #1 what is the `job` class? #2 aside from that the code looks ok

Comment: Check the server's error logs. it'll have more details as to what's causing the 500 error. Without that information, all we can do is guess.

Comment: without knowing what the `$jobs` array looks like after the call to the member function get_from_db(..), I have no idea.  Try print_r $jobs after that call and at least make sure that its an array.

Comment: Was my user error and didnt need the new array just array

Answer (score -2, accepted):

500 means
try  chmod 777
permissions ussually

Comment: 500 from an Ajax call in JavaScript is most likely an Apache error or PHP error, etc. `chmod` should have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Look in logs - /var/logs/apache2/error.log
And check (filter) $_GET['term'] for injection